# Linear regression not returning all coefficients

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, coefficients

I'm running linear regression with all predictors (I have 384 predictors), but only get 373 coefficients from summary. I'm wondering why does R not return all coefficients and how can I get all 384 coefficients?

```
full_lm <- lm(Y ~ ., data=dat[,2:385]) #384 predictors
coef_lm <- as.matrix(summary(full_lm)$coefficients[,4]) #only gives me 373
```

Comment: You will likely find the answer by examining the output of `summary(full_lm)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `summary(full_lm)$coefficients[,4]` returns the `p-values` not the coefficients. Now, to actually answer your question, I believe that some of your variables drop out of the estimation because they are perfectly collinear with some others. If you run `summary(full_lm)`, you will see that the estimation for these variables returns `NA` in all fields. So, they are not included in `summary(full_lm)$coefficients`. As an example:

```
x<- rnorm(1000)
x1<- 2*x
x2<- runif(1000)
eps<- rnorm(1000)
y<- 5+3*x + x1 + x2 + eps
full_lm <- lm(y ~ x + x1 + x2) 
summary(full_lm)
#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x + x1 + x2)
#
#Residuals:
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#-2.90396 -0.67761 -0.02374  0.71906  2.88259 
#
#Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  4.96254    0.06379   77.79   <2e-16 ***
#x            5.04771    0.03497  144.33   <2e-16 ***
#x1                NA         NA      NA       NA    
#x2           1.05833    0.11259    9.40   <2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 1.024 on 997 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.9546,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.9545 
#F-statistic: 1.048e+04 on 2 and 997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

coef_lm <- as.matrix(summary(full_lm)$coefficients[,1])
coef_lm
#(Intercept)    4.962538
#x  5.047709
#x2 1.058327
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way that I can extract all coefficients/p-values, including the NA ones? Thank you!

Comment: Just do 'full_lm$coefficients' or 'coef(full_lm)'. Either should work

Comment: Any way that I can extract all p-values for both NA and non-NA coefficients as well? All methods I tried for p-values ignored the NA ones. Thanks again!

Comment: If they weren't estimated, then the standard errors, the t-scores and the p-values are also NA, so there's not much to extract there. If you really need them, maybe you can merge the output from full_lm$coefficients with the output from summary(full_lm)$coefficients. I've never tried it, but I don't see why it would work.

Answer (score 0):

E.g., if some columns in your data are linear combinations of others, then the coefficient will be `NA` and if you index the way you do, it'll be omitted automatically.

```
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100)
c <- rnorm(100)
d <- b + 2*c

e <- lm(a ~ b + c + d)
```

gives

```
Call:
lm(formula = a ~ b + c + d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            b            c            d  
   0.088463    -0.008097    -0.077994           NA
```

But indexing...

```
> as.matrix(summary(e)$coefficients)[, 4]
(Intercept)           b           c 
  0.3651726   0.9435427   0.3562072
```

Comment: Ah that makes senses, I did see some NA values. Thank you!